# Spring Data JPA Select Distinct Column Pageable

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I'd like to select distinct records based on a column where not null and return a page.  The following is throwing java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01791: not a SELECTed expression.

(If I can get this to work I'd like to select distinct by a few additional columns.)

```
@Query(value="SELECT DISTINCT pm.batchId from PrintManifest pm",
//            + "where pm.batchId is not null"
        countQuery = "select count(DISTINCT pm.batchId) from PrintManifest pm",
        nativeQuery = true
)
Page<PolicyPrintManifest> findDistinctBatchId(Pageable pageable);
```

I also tried with no luck:

```
Page<PolicyPrintManifest> findDistinctByBatchIdExists(Pageable pageable);
```

What's the right way to do this query?

Comment: Since you are using pagination. If you are sorting by any key other than `batchId` you should add that to select statement

Answer (score 0):

Is PrintManifest name of the table or the entity. Remember that in native query, you have to use table name not entity name

Comment: PrintManifest is the name of the table.